# Remove escaping sequences automatically while redirecting

Tags: bash, redirect, colors, escaping

Lots of shell tools such as grep and ls can print colorful texts in the terminal. And when the output is redirected to a regular file, the escaping sequences representing colors are removed and only pure texts are written to the file. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
if [ -t 1 ]
```

to test whether `stdout` is connected to a terminal. If it is, print the escape sequences, otherwise just print plain text.

Answer (score 3):

Specifically, `grep` has a command-line switch to adjust this setting:

```
echo hello | grep ll                 # "ll" is printed in red
echo hello | grep --color=never ll   # "ll" is printed without special colouring
```

Most if not all tools that do this sort of thing will have a similar switch - `ls` does.  Check the manpages for other tools.

Another way to do this for tools that auto detect whether `stdout` is connected to the terminal or not is to trick them by piping output though `cat`:

```
echo hello | grep ll | cat           # "ll" is printed without special colouring
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue the other day and realized I had the following in my `.bashrc`

```
alias grep='grep --color=always'
```

I changed it to the following and had no further problems

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```